# how to iterate a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help to fix the script.

```
slides = {
    'blue': 'active',
    'red': 'active',
    'green': 'unactive',
    'orange': 'active',
    'navy': 'active'
}

li = []
li[:] = []
for color in slides.keys():
    li.append(color)
print(li)
```

I need the array to "LI" placed in the dictionary "slides" only items with a value of "active". then the code should be as concise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dict `items` function and list comprehension:

```
>>> [c for c,s in slides.items() if s == 'active']
['blue', 'orange', 'navy', 'red']
```

Comment: See also `dict.iteritems` in python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`if` statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement):

```
>>> slides = {
...     'blue': 'active',
...     'red': 'active',
...     'green': 'unactive',
...     'orange': 'active',
...     'navy': 'active'
... }
>>>
>>> li = []
>>> for color in slides:
...     if slides[color] == 'active': # <------
...         li.append(color)
...
>>> li
['blue', 'orange', 'navy', 'red']
```

Call to `keys()` is redundant. Iterating a dictionary yields keys.